# Value from database is not being read

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

Using EntityFramework 6.2.0

My model looks like:

```
<Table("Invoice_Totals")>
Public Class Invoice

    <Key>
    <Column("Invoice_Number")>
    Public Property IntegrationKey As Int64

    <Column("CustNum")>
    Public Property CustomerKey As String = String.Empty

    <Column("DateTime")>
    Public ReadOnly Property CreatedTime As DateTime


    <Column("Grand_Total")>
    Public Property Price As Decimal = Decimal.MaxValue

    <Column("Amt_Tendered")>
    Public Property Payment As Decimal = 0

    <Column("Amt_Change")>
    Public Property PaymentChange As Decimal = 0

End Class
```

This query:

```
Using database As PosModels.PosDatabase = PosModels.PosDatabase.CreateWithNoProxies
    Dim q As IQueryable(Of PosModels.Invoice) = database.Invoices
    posInvoices = q.ToList
End Using
```

produces this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Invoice_Number] AS [Invoice_Number], 
    [Extent1].[CustNum] AS [CustNum], 
    [Extent1].[Grand_Total] AS [Grand_Total], 
    [Extent1].[Amt_Tendered] AS [Amt_Tendered], 
    [Extent1].[Amt_Change] AS [Amt_Change]
    FROM [dbo].[Invoice_Totals] AS [Extent1]
```

As you can see, the column `[DateTime]` is not included in the query.  I assume because "DateTime" is a SQL keyword/data type.  Is there any way to get EF to perform this query correctly?

Even when performing the query "manually" the object mapper does not appear to kick in:

```
posInvoices = database.Database.SqlQuery(Of PosModels.Invoice)($"
                SELECT 
                    [Extent1].[Invoice_Number] AS [IntegrationKey], 
                    [Extent1].[CustNum] AS [CustomerKey], 
                    [Extent1].[DateTime] AS [CreatedTime],
                    [Extent1].[Grand_Total] AS [Price], 
                    [Extent1].[Amt_Tendered] AS [Payment], 
                    [Extent1].[Amt_Change] AS [PaymentChange]
                    FROM [dbo].[Invoice_Totals] AS [Extent1]
            ").ToList
```

This still does not fill in any values for the `CreatedTime` property.  As in the previous query, all values in the model remain at `DateTime.MinValue`.  The oldest data in the database is from 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared that as a ReadOnly property

```
 Public ReadOnly Property CreatedTime As DateTime
```

Which means that only a constructor can set it.  EF Core supports [Backing Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field), which can be used to implement Read Only properties.  But in EF6 all Properties mapping to database columns must be read/write.